# ESLint configuration for JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I want configure ESLint for check my JSX files but my configuration doesn't work. What is the correct way?

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  parser: 'babel-eslint'
};
```

Comment: What is the error or problem you are having?

Comment: Eslint don't scan jsx files.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to lint JSX files configuration alone is not enough. Your configuration looks fine (although you probably don't need `babel-eslint`, unless you are using features that are lower than stage 4 proposal). By default ESLint will only process `.js` files. You have to tell it that you want to process `.jsx` files as well by using `--ext` flag on command line: `eslint --ext .jsx .`

Comment: Now ESLint scan jsx but not js

Comment: `eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js .` will scan both.

Comment: This keep it less verbose `eslint --ext .js,.jsx .`

Comment: Can drop the preceding extension dot like: `eslint --ext js,jsx .`

Answer (score 15):

I found an alternative to the original answer so that you don't have to specify the arguments when running `eslint` command.

#### Option 1

Use the command `eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx`

#### Option 2

Specify `overrides` in your eslint config...

```
//.eslintrc
{
  ...
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.jsx", "*.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Option 2 only works if all of the rules are placed within this override object, which is not useful if you're extending other configurations.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use also the plugin for eslint https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

You could do this example config:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  'extends': [ 'plugin:react/recommended' ],
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaFeatures': {
      'jsx': true
    }
  },
  'plugins': [ 'react' ],
  'rules': {

    // React
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 'error',
    'react/no-multi-comp': [ 'error', { 'ignoreStateless': true }],
    'react/no-set-state': 'error',
    'react/no-string-refs': 'error',
    'react/prefer-es6-class': 'error',
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': 'error',
    'react/require-extension': 'error',
    'react/require-render-return': 'error',
    'react/self-closing-comp': 'error',
    'react/sort-comp': 'error',
    'react/sort-prop-types': 'error',
    'react/wrap-multilines': 'error',

    // JSX
    'react/jsx-boolean-value': 'error',
    'react/jsx-closing-bracket-location': 'error',
    'react/jsx-curly-spacing': [ 'error', 'always' ],
    'react/jsx-equals-spacing': 'error',
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': 'error',
    'react/jsx-handler-names': 'error',
    'react/jsx-indent-props': [ 'error', 2 ],
    'react/jsx-indent': [ 'error', 2 ],
    'react/jsx-key': 'error',
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': [ 'error', { 'maximum': 3 }],
    'react/jsx-no-bind': 'error',
    'react/jsx-no-literals': 'off',
    'react/jsx-no-target-blank': 'error',
    'react/jsx-pascal-case': 'error',
    'react/jsx-sort-props': 'error',
    'react/jsx-space-before-closing': 'error'
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this `eslint` config file enough good for a little project with 3 developers along side ?

Comment: Yes it could be suitable, or you could use a config like https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb which comes with a lot of good stuff already out of the box

Comment: But I saw some articles about `airbnb`, In these articles were wrote `airbnb` eslint is annoying and make development hard and slow. Is it right?

Comment: I think the point of eslint is to put HARD restrictions on how the code is written. Airbnb config is industry standard, if your developers complain it might be because they don't use estrict configs. I personally think that is very good to have a very tight eslint configuration that doesn't allow lazy developers do what they think is easy.

Comment: It's not just about being strict on code style, airbnb has good rules that detect potential bugs, performance issues, and other things

Comment: Thanks a lot, Definitely I use it in my next project. Undoubtedly I will do it. But first I should R&D about it and study how can I settle it in my case.